# When is KeyboardInterrupt raised in Python?

Tags: python, exception, keyboardinterrupt

All the docs tell us is,

> Raised when the user hits the interrupt key (normally `Control-C` or `Delete`). During execution, a check for interrupts is made regularly.

But **from the point of the code, when can I see this exception?** Does it occur during statement execution? Only between statements? Can it happen in the middle of an expression?

For example:

```
file_ = open('foo')
# <-- can a KeyboardInterrupt be raised here, after the successful
# completion of open but prior to the try? -->
try:
    # try some things with file_
finally:
    # cleanup
```

Will this code leak during a well-timed `KeyboardInterrupt`? Or is it raised during the execution of some statements or expressions?

Answer (score 6):

According to a note in the unrelated [PEP 343](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0343/):

> Even if you write bug-free code, a KeyboardInterrupt exception can still cause it to exit between any two virtual machine opcodes.

So it can occur essentially anywhere.  It can indeed occur during evaluation of a single expression.  (This shouldn't be surprising, since an expression can include function calls, and pretty much anything can happen inside a function call.)

Answer (score 3):

Yes, a `KeyboardInterrupt` can occur in the place you marked.

To deal with this, you should use a `with` block:

```
with open('foo') as file_:
    # do some things
    raise KeyboardInterrupt

# file resource is closed no matter what, even if a KeyboardInterrupt is raised
```

However, the exception could occur even between the `open()` call and the assignment to `file_`. It's probably not worth worrying about this, because usually a <kbd>ctrl-c</kbd> will mean your program is about to end, so the "leaked" file handle will be cleaned up by the OS. But if you know that it is important, you can use [a signal handler](https://docs.python.org/2/library/signal.html) to catch the signal that raises KeyboardInterrupt (SIGINT).

Comment: Unfortunately, a `with` is not always possible; sometimes you want to see if the expression in the with statement fails (e.g., did it raise a particular expcetion?) prior to calling `__enter__`. You cannot do this with `with`, because you lose the ability to wrap the expression without wrapping the body of the `with`. (Which, if it can raise the same type of exception as the with-expression, means you cannot distinguish them in your `except`.)